# How to work out if a member of a struct was set or not?

Tags: c, function, struct, variable-assignment, standard-library

Say I have the following struct:

```
struct cube {  
    int height;
    int length;
    int width;
};
```

I need to create a library that allows the user to enter values into the struct and then pass it into a function, which will determine whether the user wants either the `area` or the `volume` from the values provided.

For example:

```
int main() {
    struct cube shape;

    shape.height = 2;
    shape.width = 3;

    printf("Area: %d", calculate(shape)); // Prints 6

    shape.length = 4;
    printf("Volume: %d", calculate(shape)); // Prints 24

    return 0;
}

int calculate(struct cube nums) {
    if (is_present(nums.height, nums) && is_present(nums.width, nums)) {
        return nums.height * nums.width;
    }

    else if (is_present(nums.height, nums) && is_present(nums.width, nums) && is_present(nums.length, nums)) {
        return nums.height * nums.width * nums.length;
    }
    else {
        return -1; // Error
    }
}
```

This should work, if I can use a function (like `is_present()`, which I just made up) to work out if a value was given to a member of a struct.

Is there such a function and if not, how could this be implemented?

Comment: There is not, you have to do something, like giving -1 to height/length/width and then test it (in place of your is_present function). Or you can do an opaque struct and have a get/set function. This way, you know.

Comment: Why would you allow an invalid instance of `cube` to exist ? Why not just avoid this issue by checking for missing fields *before* you create it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize your fields to something that is out of the domain of the possible values. For example, for such dimensions, which are positive numbers, a negative value could act as a "not assigned" value.

Also, I reordered your `if` statements: the one checking for all the fields should be the first.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOT_PRESENT -1
#define is_present(x) ((x) != NOT_PRESENT)

struct cube {  
    int height;
    int length;
    int width;
};

int calculate(struct cube);

int main() {
    struct cube shape = {
        .height = NOT_PRESENT,
        .length = NOT_PRESENT,
        .width = NOT_PRESENT,
    };

    shape.height = 2;
    shape.width = 3;

    printf("Area: %d\n", calculate(shape)); // Prints 6

    shape.length = 4;
    printf("Volume: %d\n", calculate(shape)); // Prints 24

    return 0;
}

int calculate(struct cube nums) {
    if (is_present(nums.height) && is_present(nums.width) && is_present(nums.length)) {
        return nums.height * nums.width * nums.length;
    } else if (is_present(nums.height) && is_present(nums.width)) {
        return nums.height * nums.width;
    } else {
        return -1; // Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to clearly define what "`a value was given`" means to your domain. A member initialized to 0 means no value was given?

A simple solution is to initialize your struct with 0 (for example), and just compare each member against it. Example:

```
struct cube shape = {0};
shape.width = 3;
if (shape.width != 0)
    printf("width was set");
```

Or simpler:

```
struct cube shape = {2,0,3};
if (shape.width != 0)
    printf("width was set");
```